# Kinesin-5 / cytoplasmic dynein spatial density distribution in neurons

Tags: molecular-biology, neuroscience, biophysics

Is there some way to experimentally determine the density distribution of Kinesin and Dynein in a Neuron?
Fluorescence labeling would be impossible(?) as GFP markers would probably alter the motor dynamics.
Any ideas? Or do any studies exist which looked into this topic?

Comment: I have next to no knowledge of this area, but I do know that [Peter Baas](https://www.drexelmed.edu/Home/AboutOurFaculty/PeterBaas.aspx) has done extensive studies of Kinesin-5 in neuronal growth cones during development.  I mention that in the off chance that some of his imaging techniques might be helpful to you.

Comment: Are you sure that GFP tagged motors don't function properly in these two cases? I'm almost certain I've seen motors tagged before.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to tag molecular motors with fluorescent proteins. It may impede with its movement but as [this](http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pbio.1000216) paper describes, a variant can be created that doesn't have cargo binding ability.

> Constitutively active kinesin motors can be generated by truncations
>   that remove autoinhibitory and cargo-binding regions of the
>   polypeptide. For this work, we generated KHC(1-560) (Figure 1A), a
>   dimeric motor that has been well characterized in vitro and in vivo
>   [16],[18],[19]. KHC(1-560) motors were tagged with three tandem copies
>   of monomeric Citrine (mCit), a variant of enhanced yellow fluorescent
>   protein (FP) (Figure 1A), and expressed in COS cells (Figure 1B).
>   Single Kinesin-1 motors were tracked in live cells using a modified
>   TIRF microscope (Figure 1C) in which the angle of illumination was
>   varied to enable deeper imaging as described [17]

However, if your objective is just *to determine the density distribution of Kinesin and Dynein in a Neuron*, you can simply fix the cells and do IHC staining for the motor proteins followed by high resolution imaging.